# Does Anyone know which methods are Deprecated in IOS 6.0?  

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6

Does Anyone know, how many methods are **Deprecated IOS 6.0**?
For example:

1)
`– shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` Deprecated in iOS 6.0

**Instead use**

```
– shouldAutorotate
```

2)

`– dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` Deprecated in iOS 6.0

`– presentModalViewController:animated:` Deprecated in iOS 6.0

**Instead use**

```
– presentViewController:animated:completion:

– dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:
```

**Another one**

```
– viewDidUnload Deprecated in iOS 6.0

– viewWillUnload Deprecated in iOS 6.0
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For instance you can check for [Deprecated methods for NSArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html) and [Deprecated methods for CLLocationManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html)

List is long but you can google it.

Comment: Can u list out the methods deprecated in iOS 7!

Comment: @ManoChitraR What list are you seeking ?

Comment: methods that  are Deprecated in IOS 7.0

Comment: @ManoChitraR check [this documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS7.html) you can find out those details there.

Answer (score 19):

Changes in iOS 6, List of deprecated methods links

http://www.bgr.com/2012/07/16/ios-6-download-beta-3-change-log/

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-6_0/_index.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/_index.html

http://blog.twistedhq.com/post/31539631405/whats-new-in-the-new-apple-app-store-guidelines

http://www.bgr.com/2012/07/16/ios-6-download-beta-3-change-log/

http://9to5mac.com/2012/06/25/apple-pushes-ios-6-0-update-to-devs/

Check them out !!! :)

Comment: Can u list out the methods deprecated in iOS 7!

Answer (score 0):

its long list between iOS 6 and iOS 7 there is uiallignment is replaced from nsallignment