# Is there any thing need to be change or configure when update iOS 5 to iOS 6 to run existing Xcode app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6

I have updated the iOS 5 to iOS 6 . Is there need to change or configure  any settings to run existing application on the Xcode ?

Answer (score 0):

Well there are a list of deprecated methods which you should view inorder to run your iOS 5 applications in iOS 6. This is because lower version apps do not run in upper versions.

Here check this link I had provided an answer of deprecated methods before :) .

[Does Anyone know which methods are Deprecated in IOS 6.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12793311/does-anyone-know-which-methods-are-deprecated-in-ios-6-0/12793347#12793347)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your application, the best for you would be to go through [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-6_0/_index.html) on apples developer site in order to have look at all what you need to change.
And ya on the whole you will definitely need to work out on the rotation API which has been depreciated in IOS6.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using static libs you should check that they have the armv7s slice, otherwise you should force to armv7 only

Also if you want to support iphone5 you'll have to add a default image name it Default-568h@2x.png

And also check that your view displays correctly on a 4 inch screen, if not try playing with your autoresizing masks before going to handle that directly in the code. Of course if you want to support only ios6 you can check out Auto Layout